# Google Engine - Segmentation

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-segmentation

From the **Google Engine scripts**,

Is it available any **Segmentation tool** like the ArcMap "Segmentation Mean Shift" from ArcMap? I´m looking for *crop-fields limit detection*.
I tried the SNIC one explained by Gorelick at the 2018 Google Engine Summit ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2R0aTaMtYTY), [slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1p_W06MwdhRFZjkb7imYkuTchatY5nxb5aTRgh6qm2uU/view#slide=id.p)), but it needs the "Crop Data Layer" as an input, and I am located at Argentina. Maybe a SNIC workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SNIC](https://ivrl.epfl.ch/research-2/research-current/research-superpixels/research-snic_superpixels/) is just an algorithm, so it can be applied to the layer you want to segment. The "Crop Data Layer" is just an example layer.

I give you a simple example:

```js
// site
var p = ee.Geometry.Point([-62.44, -38.40])
var site = p.buffer(10000)
// Sentinel 2 collection filtered
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
           .filterBounds(p)
           .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT', 'less_than', 20)
// get the first image
var image = ee.Image(s2.first()).clip(site)    
// visualize the image
var vis = {bands:['B8', 'B11', 'B4'], min:0, max:5000}
Map.addLayer(image, vis, 'Image Sentinel 2')    
// segmentation with size 30
var snic = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC(image, 30)
// watch results of segmentation
Map.addLayer(snic.randomVisualizer(), null, 'SNIC')
```

Comment: This is why I love StackExchange! I think my problem was starting to use this algorithm by Gorelick´s complex example. Thanks Rodrigo!

Comment: Your welcome @AlfonsodeLara! Greetings from la Patagonia Argentina =)